# Calling variables from other function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and currently trying to get variables inside a function to work outside of it and currently met a wall where I can't seem to get it work.

The scenario is that I want to change the URL via a dropdown form using a combination of Javascript and HTML. If I put the if else statement inside the function it'll work flawlessly but in my scenario, I need to put it outside of the function and it doesn't work even after I made the variable global.

I've tried several solutions from questions that related to my issue, but it doesn't seems to work for my scenario.

Here's the code I'm currently using.

```js
var documentLink = document.getElementById('documentLink');

function getDocument(option) {
  chosenDocument = option.value;
}

if (chosenDocument === "Google") {
  documentLink.href = "https://www.google.com";
} else if (chosenDocument === "duckduckgo") {
  documentLink.href = "https://www.duckduckgo.com";
}
```

Comment: You're never calling `getDocument`, so `chosenDocument` will never be set.

Comment: BTW, you should not use `getElementById` (nor `querySelector`) **until after** the `DOMContentLoaded` event, otherwise they wont work reliably.

Comment: @Ivar Oh! so outside of the function, all I have to do is to add getDocument(); ? I'm sorry if this is trivial, I'm really new to JavaScript.

Comment: Well, a function doesn't run by itself. You indeed need to invoke it, but you must do so before the `chosenDocument === "Google"` line, otherwise it will not have the right value.

Comment: What is `documentLink`? Is it a `select` element?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @Andy Hello, Andy, yes, it's a select element, it's where the href located. I've made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vob5prna/

Comment: Next time you can click the button shaped like this `[<>]` in the editor and give us a snippet here instead

Comment: @mplungjan Understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely what you meant to do.

Note I use recommended [eventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // when elements are available in page
  const documentLink = document.getElementById('documentLink');
  
  document.getElementById("searchSites").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const chosenSite = this.value;
    if (chosenSite === "Google") { // this could be done nicer with a lookup table
      documentLink.href = "https://www.google.com";
    } else if (chosenSite === "duckduckgo") {
      documentLink.href = "https://www.duckduckgo.com";
    }
  })
  
  documentLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
    if (this.getAttribute("href") === "") { // not set 
      e.preventDefault(); // stop link
      alert("Please select a site first");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<select id="searchSites">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Google">Google</option>
  <option value="duckduckgo">duckduckgo</option>
</select><br/>
<a href="" id="documentLink">GO</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mplungjan ! I can learn so much from the syntax you've given.

Comment: @Angga You are welcome. And you got the lookuptable I suggested from Andy

Comment: The `load` event is inappropriate because it can occur potentially _minutes_ after the HTML was fully loaded, instead use the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which is the actual point at which `getElementById` and `querySelector` can be safely used.

Comment: I always used load. It seems to work everywhere I use it and is shorter to type than DOMContentLoaded  but I have looked at it and will use DOMContentLoaded  from now on if I can spell it right

Answer (score 0):

When put your codes directly in the body of the "script" tag, It will execute only once (when the script loads).
You need to put your codes in a place that can run more than once, for example, put it in a function and call that when an event triggers

If you need that "if" block run every time the dropdown value changes you have these options:
1- move your code into the getDocument function
2- move your "if" block into a new function and then call it in the
getDocument function

or 3- move your "if" block into a new function and then assign it to another event coincides with the dropdown event (like dropdown onchange, or dropdown onblur)

Comment: I went with your suggestion for number two and it works, thank you so much, Samir!

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your code to be executed in DOMContentLoaded event.
2. Move getDocument function outside of this event listener.
3. I am assuming you already have a select option event listener and you have a variable named SelectOption with selected value

You may try below code:

```js
<script>
  // Function extracts and returns value from provided parameter
  function getDocumentValue(option) {
    return option.value;
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
    const documentLink = document.getElementById('documentLink'); // Id is fine if we are sure it wont be duplicated.
    const chosenDocument =  getDocumentValue(SelectOption);

    if (chosenDocument === "Google" ) {
        documentLink.href = "https://www.google.com";
        } else if (chosenDocument === "duckduckgo") {
        documentLink.href = "https://www.duckduckgo.com";
    }   
 })
            
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Add some description 2. if you use a snippet make it a working snippet.

Comment: added description.

Answer (score 0):

The comments under your question outline the key issues. I just wanted to quickly add an alternative approach that, as you're just starting out with JS, you may find interesting.

```js
// Select the element
const select = document.querySelector('select');

// Add an event listener to it to watch out for changes
// and when that listener is fired call the handleChange function
select.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

// Here is an object containing routes
// The keys map directly to the values of the options
const routes = {
  google: 'https://www.google.com',
  duckduckgo: 'https://www.duckduckgo.com'
}

// So that when the function is called all
// we need to do is get the value of that particular route
function handleChange() {
  console.log(routes[this.value]);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="google">Google</option>
  <option value="duckduckgo">duckduckgo</option>
</select>
```

Additional documentation

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Thank you so much @Andy ! The comments really help me to understand better. I'm really sorry that I can't upvote yet since I don't have enough reps and it seems like I can't give a green tick to more than one answer.

Comment: No problem, @Angga. Sometimes it's just good to help people. Happy coding!

Comment: PS @Angga I added some further reading from the [MDN documentation website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) that you might find useful.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is with [scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). Declare the variable outside so that it is in window scope, not function scope:

```js
var documentLink = document.getElementById('documentLink');
var chosenDocument;

function getDocument(option) {
    chosenDocument = option.value;
}
 
            
if (chosenDocument === "Google" ) {
    documentLink.href = "https://www.google.com";
} else if (chosenDocument === "duckduckgo") {
    documentLink.href = "https://www.duckduckgo.com";
}
```

Alternatively, you can change your function to return a value (its naming indicates, it returns something):

```js
var documentLink = document.getElementById('documentLink');

function getDocument(option) {
    return option.value;
}
 
            
if (getDocument() === "Google" ) {
    documentLink.href = "https://www.google.com";
} else if (getDocument() === "duckduckgo") {
    documentLink.href = "https://www.duckduckgo.com";
}
```

Comment: `chosenDocument` isn't declared in `getDocument()`, so it isn't scoped to that function. Also, given that `getDocument()` isn't invoked before `chosenDocument` is accessed, it still wont hold the expected value.